# Resizing UIScrollView for 3.5 and 4 inch screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-5

I am currently working on updating my application to support the new 4 inch screen size.  I am noticing a few UI issues, particularly with `UIScrollViews`.  I would like to get a scrollview to stretch to fill the screen when there is empty space below it; whitespace is the result of the scrollview not stretching on the 4 inch screen size.  Currently, I am adjusting the scrollviews frame during the `viewDidAppear` method of my VC to accommodate for this.  However, I am wondering if it is possible to handle this through IB.

I have played around with the autosizing options through IB with no luck.  I have also tried setting the size to the "Retina 4 Full Screen" option and am noticing the opposite, the scrollview is not shrinking to fit the 3.5 inch screen size.

There has to be a simple way of doing this through IB.

Comment: add the UIScroll view code.. and what is the content size you have set?

Answer (score 2):

I have only been able to simply use a `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height` attribute to set the size automatically, but that's pretty painless.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;